# Easy or default way to exclue rows with NA values from individual operations and comparisons

Tags: r, na

I work with survey data, where missing values are the rule rather than the exception. My datasets always have lots of NAs, and for simple statistics *I usually want to work with cases that are complete on the subset of variables required for that specific operation, and ignore the other cases*.

Most of R's base functions return NA if there are any NAs in the input. Additionally, subsets using comparison operators will return a row of NAs for any row with an NA on one of the variables. I literally never want either of these behaviors.

I would like for R to default to excluding rows with NAs for the variables it's operating on, and returning results for the remaining rows (see example below).

Here are the workarounds I currently know about:

1. Specify `na.rm=T`: Not too bad, but not all functions support it.
2. Add `!is.na()` to all comparison operations: Works, but it's annoying and error-prone to do this by hand, especially when there are multiple variables involved.
3. Use `complete.cases()`: Not helpful because I don't want to exclude cases that are missing *any* variable, just the variables being used in the current operation.
4. Create a new data frame with the desired cases: Often each row is missing a few scattered variables. That means that every time I wanted to switch from working with one variable to another, I'd have to explicitly create a new subset.
5. Use imputation: Not always appropriate, especially when computing descriptives or just examining the data.

I know how to get the desired results for any given case, but dealing with NAs explicitly for every piece of code I write takes up a lot of time. Hopefully there's some simple solution that I'm missing. But complex or partial solutions would also be welcome.

**Example:**

```
> z<-data.frame(x=c(413,612,96,8,NA), y=c(314,69,400,NA,8888))

# current behavior: 
> z[z$x < z$y ,]

      x   y
3    96 400
NA   NA  NA
NA.1 NA  NA

# Desired behavior:
> z[z$x < z$y ,]

      x   y
3    96 400

# What I currently have to do in order to get the desired output:
> z[(z$x < z$y) & !is.na(z$x) & !is.na(z$y) ,]

      x   y
3    96 400
```

Comment: the `na.omit` function may be handy here: `na.omit(z[z$x < z$y ,])`

Comment: Depending on how you are using this in your code, you might try `subset` instead of extract (`[`). This gives the desired behavior: `subset(z, x < y)`.

Answer (score 1):

One trick for dealing with NAs in inequalities when subsetting is to do

```
z[which(z$x < z$y),]

#    x   y
# 3 96 400
```

The `which()` silently drops NA values.

Comment: Less typing, and doesn't grow with the number of variables involved. Definitely an improvement!